# Как правильно тестировать работу с кэшем в Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

У меня есть метод, который должен получить данные из кэша, если их там нет, сделать запрос во внешний сервис. Соответственно пишется на это тест, который проверяет, что данные пришли из кэша или из внешнего источника.

В Laravel мой код упрощенно выглядит примерно как-то так:

```
public function getExternalData($key)
{
    $response = Cache::get($key, null);

    if (!$response) {
        $response = $this->externalSource->getData($key); // heavy and complicated request
        Cache::set($key, $response;
    }

    return response;
}
```

а код тестов:

```
public function testFromCache($returnData)
{
    Cache::shouldReceive('get')->once()->andReturn($returnData);
}

public function testFromSource($returnData)
{
    Cache::shouldReceive('get')->once()->andReturn(null);

    $externalSourceMock = $this->partialMock(
        Source::class,
        function (MockInterface $mock) use ($returnData) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('getData')->once()->andReturn($returnData);
        }
    );

    Cache::shouldReceive('set')->once()->andReturn(true);
}
```

В симфони немного по-другому устроено кэширование, поэтому код сложнее:

```
public function __construct(
    private HttpClientInterface $client,
    private CacheInterface $cache,
    private LoggerInterface $logger
) {
}

public function getExternalData( $key ) {
    $responseDto = $this->cache->get($key, function () use ($key) {
        $response = $this->externalSource->getData($key); // heavy and complicated request
        return $response;
    });
}
```

Общий вопрос звучит так: Как правильно написать тесты, аналогичные вышеописанным для symfony?
Более мелкие вопросы:

1. Как проверить наличие или отсутствие данных ИМЕННО в кэше?
2. Как замокать правильно результат запроса во внешний сервис внутри callable-функции?
3. Нужно ли проверять запись в кэш в таком коде, если да, то как?

Answer (score 0):

я бы переписал код немного по другому

```
public function __construct(
    private HttpClientInterface $client,
    private CacheInterface $cache,
    private LoggerInterface $logger
) {
}

public function getExternalData( $key ) {
    if (!($response = $this->cache->get($key))) {
        $response = $this->externalSource->getData($key);
        $this->cache->set($key, $response);
    }

    return $response;
}
```

Далее можно замокать `CacheInterface::get` для разных случаев - отдавать респонс (в кеше что-то есть) либо отдавать null (в кеше еще ничего нет)

Теперь

- если Unit тесты - передать мок кешера в конструктор и дернуть метод
- если Functional тесты - положить мок в DI-контейнер и дернуть функционал

Также, можно проверить факт записи в кеш, замокав `CacheInterface::set` и проверив, что метод дернулся один раз, с параметрами `$key, $response`

Примерно для PHPUnit

```
$cache = $this->createMock(CacheInterface::class);
$cache->expects($this->once())
    ->method('set')
    ->with($key, $response)
```

Или не дернулся (если в кеше уже что-то есть)

```
$cache = $this->createMock(CacheInterface::class);
$cache->expects($this->never())
    ->method('set')
    ->with($key, $response)
```

Comment: $this->cache->get($key) В целом я бы так и написал  но в symfony 6.2 вторым аргументом обязательно должен идти callback

Comment: используйте `Psr\SimpleCache\CacheInterface`, симфони это допускает